# Zsh function does not terminate when ${name:?word} fails

Tags: zsh

*(Question already posted on [Unix Forum](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/268241-zsh-function-does-not-terminate-when-name-word-fails.html), but didn't get any response)*

I have in my .zshrc the following function definition (simplified example):

```
function foo {
  local p=${1:?parameter missing}
  echo continue ....
}
```

Running the function by just typing `foo` produces, as expected, the message *parameter missing*, but it also outputs *continue*. I had expected that the function terminates when the `:?` check fails, but it continues to run. Why is this the case?

The man-page zshexpn says about `:?`:

`... otherwise, print word and exit from the shell. Interactive shells instead return to the prompt.`

I found that the behaviour I am experiencing depends on the presence or absence of the `local` specifier. If I remove `local`, the function works as expected, i.e. returns from the function immediately, if no parameter is passed.

Since I need `local` in my application, I rewrote the function like this:

```
function foo {
  : ${1:?parameter missing}
  local p=$1
  echo continue ....
}
```

This works fine, but I still am curious to know, why the presence of `local` in combination with a `:?` causes this difference in behaviour.

**UPDATE** : I posted the issue also on the Zsh mailing list, and the zsh developers confirmed that this is a bug in Zsh.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in `zsh` 5.0.8. The first definition of `foo` returns to the prompt in an interactive shell without outputting "continue".

Comment: Hm, I *can* reproduce this in 5.2, though, so either it's a new bug, or the explanation you looking for exists.